# Capture motion videos of the smarthone saved directly in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I'm wondering if it's possible to save  the video of my smarphone (Android) video surveillance camera directly in Google Drive. So far I found only method which allows to synchronize a shared folder between the device and Google Drive. I'd like to avoid this because I don't have enough memory space.

Comment: You need a camera app with built-in GDrive support. Then may be videos can be saved to GDrive directly.

Comment: Hello @Robert can you suggest to me any app to reach the goal?